# How to share JWT Tokens across Multiple Applications (Web / Mobile) when using identity server 3.0 and oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a Secure Token server built on Identity Server 3.0 that manages security across, multiple applications both Single Page and Native Mobile applications. And there are resource server(s) (a RESTful API that needs to be accessed by the aforesaid applications). Mobile application gives a summarised view of the Client information where as user need to navigate to the Single Page application to get the complete view of the client.

At present the mobile application (Cordova) retrieves client information summary from the resource server through Resource Owner Client Credential Grant and displays List of Client information in the Form of a Grid in the Cordova App.

The requirement now is to open the Client Details information (Details View) in the single page application (AngularJS) without making the user login again. At this point the mobile app possesses a token that can access the resource server (scope).

The problem now is how to pass the token we have to the Single Page application (AngularJS) without sending it (the token) in the URL. Could some please shed some light on what is the best possible way to handle the scenario?

Comment: So you want to stay authenticated in the mobile phone web browser whenever the user is authenticated in the app? Big applications like Facebook don't even do that which might help indicate some potential security risks with that approach

Comment: Why tag this question IdentityServer4 when you are using IdentityServer 3?

Comment: Sorry i added identity server 4.0 because, couldn't find the identity server 3.0

Answer (score 9):

Make sure all your platform share the same **"secret"**

Comment: what is the secret over here? Is it the "client_secret" that we get when we register our application on identity server and receive client_id & client_secret?

Comment: Secret in the signature, see https://jwt.io/introduction signature section

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a Single Sign-On (SSO) behavior among two applications. But there is an issue with the current flow you use.

As you are currently using `Resource Owner Client Credential Grant`, you are not using the end user login of identity server. Instead, I believe you obtain end user credentials from mobile app and invoke token endpoint to obtain tokens.

From OAuth/OpenID Connect perspective, SSO is implemented on top of browser cookies. How it works ?

```
1. App A follow a flow that utilize front channel login (ex:-
Authorization code flow with PKCE)
2. End user is present with login page of Identity Server
3. App A completes the flow and obtain tokens
4. App B use a flow utilize front channel login
4. Identity server get login request and see cookies which correlate previously logged in user
5. Because of cookies, log in page is skipped and optionally consent page will be  showed
6. App B completes the flow and obtain tokens
```

This is how SSO works and as you can see it require browser involvement. And I think this is the right way to solve the issue.

Also, from OAuth/OpenID Connect principals, client is discouraged to obtain end user credentials. Your client flow is okay if application is privileged or cannot use browser involvement ([source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason we are using Resource Owner Client Credentials Grant is because Majority of the Web services the Mobile App (Cordova), uses are not governed by OAUTH, they are SOAP services with Basic Authentication. So unfortunately the application is anyway collecting user name / password for the user, therefore at that point we use the Client Credentials grant (as the user/pwd is already collected) to obtain a token that enables the mobile application to access the new API server. That’s why I was wondering if there is way to do what I was trying to do here.

Comment: I can get the big picture. If you can simply use access tokens to invoke (new) APIs from mobile application itself, then that would be straightforward. But you need two different applications to share same token. And that also a mobile APP and a SPA. From protocol perspective sharing tokens is not supported and from security point of view should not be practiced. What if you simply let user login to SPA ones and use a remember me feature to remember logged in state (if supported by Identity server) ?

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Core 3.1 and JWT token**

When First API has a logic of authentication, you can use the same configuration for the second API. After the authentication, you can send the JWT token over HTTPHeader (Authorize), which can be understood by the second API since it has the same configuration/ key value.

**Appsettings.json:**

```
"Jwt": {
"Key": "IamThePrivateKey",
"Issuer": "ImTheIssuer",
"Audience": "ImTheAudience"
 },
```

**The same configuration can be used wherever the API that is looking for the token, which doesn't require reauthentication.**

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
        {
            option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "My API ",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "My RESTful API"
            });
            
            option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "My API Authorization",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "bearer"
            });

            option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });

        } );

        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(option =>
        {
            option.SaveToken = true;
            option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                SaveSigninToken = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], //from Appsettings.json
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], //from Appsettings.json
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])) 
//from Appsettings.json
            };
        });

        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.Populate(services);

        //new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());            
    }
```